# Create crystal reports without using xsd file

Tags: c#, wcf, crystal-reports

I need some help in figuring out this issue.

Basically, I have a `Wcf` service that generates reports using crystal report. Crystal report uses XSD for data source.

I want to remove `XSD` and use a data service (`WCF`) that connects to database and provides results.

In a nutsell, trying to separate report logic from data logic, not sure how to get started on this if there are any examples that showcase this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF Data Services is the implementation of the OData protocol by Microsoft. To use the OData protocol for Crystal Reports you can use the following steps:
First you have to create a DataSet in your project, defining your data model. Based on this DataSet you can build your CR with the DataSet as data source.
After this you have to map your incoming data from OData service to your DataSet. this can be done simiar to the following example where I map data from the SFlight data model to the DataSet which is the base for my CR:

```
static private void generateCRFlight(DataTable inDataTable)
    {
        //Create data set to be consumed by crystal report
        DataSetFlight dataSetFlight = new DataSetFlight();
        DataTable theDataTable = dataSetFlight.Tables.Add(("FlightData"));
        theDataTable.Columns.Add("CarrID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        theDataTable.Columns.Add("ConnID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        theDataTable.Columns.Add("FlDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
        theDataTable.Columns.Add("Price", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
        theDataTable.Columns.Add("Currency", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        theDataTable.Columns.Add("PlaneType", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        theDataTable.Columns.Add("SeatsMax", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        theDataTable.Columns.Add("SeatsOcc", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

        int rowCounter = 0;
        int numberOfRows = inDataTable.Rows.Count;

        for (rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < numberOfRows; rowCounter++)
        {
            DataRow theDataRow = theDataTable.NewRow();
            theDataRow[0] = inDataTable.Rows[rowCounter][0];
            theDataRow[1] = inDataTable.Rows[rowCounter][1];
            theDataRow[2] = inDataTable.Rows[rowCounter][2];
            theDataRow[3] = inDataTable.Rows[rowCounter][3];
            theDataRow[4] = inDataTable.Rows[rowCounter][4];
            theDataRow[5] = inDataTable.Rows[rowCounter][5];
            theDataRow[6] = inDataTable.Rows[rowCounter][6];
            theDataTable.Rows.Add(theDataRow);
        }

        CRFlight theCrystalReport = new CRFlight();
        theCrystalReport.SetDataSource(dataSetFlight.Tables[1]);
        ReportViewer theReportViewer = new ReportViewer(theCrystalReport);
        theReportViewer.Show();
    }
```

See as well the following article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreatingCrystalReports.aspx

[Source](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1775517)